# Loading an image view with saved image in segue

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am using following code to assign an image to an ImageView

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"imgHand"])
   {
      RingController *ctrl =  segue.destinationViewController ;
      ctrl.imgHand.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:self.selectedPath];
   }
}
```

However the imgHand shows black and no image is assigned to it.

Image at this path does exist and have already assigned it to an image in CollectionView

```
Printing description of self->selectedPath:
/var/mobile/Applications/79092B1E-BE77-4583-A39A-C2D4767ADA12/Documents/myHandImage1.png
```

Comment: And, what's the issue? I don't see a question here.

Comment: @dpassage sorry, i edited the code, the image is not assigning to imgHand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your "`imgHand`" image view property isn't insantiated or fully synthesized in the parent view controller's "`prepareForSegue`" method.  It's a NULL object at that point.

Expose a standalone "`UIImage`" property from your "`RingController`" and you can set the image via the parent's "`prepareForSegue`" method call, then in `RingController`'s "`viewDidLoad:`" you can set the image view to be the image.

Comment: perfect that helped a lot :)